# How to access a particular element in prettytable in python?

Tags: python, prettytable

I am trying to access a particular element say in row=1 and column=2 ..how can I access elements like dat in pretty table in python?

Comment: Please add the minimal code that you have tried instead of just posting as a question

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the row by index : row = table[index]
row is a prettytable. you need to set border and header to false and then you can get the specific field by name.

here a code example to get first "City name":

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"]
x.add_row(["Adelaide", 1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane", 5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])

row = x[0]
row.border = False
row.header = False
z = row.get_string(fields=["City name"]).strip()
print(z)
```